# Mysterious violet-purple compound in "Gerber Method" & "Banana oil synthesis"

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, food-chemistry, precipitation, identification

During the determination of fat in milk (Gerber method), in a milk butyrometer are mixed milk + $\ce{H2SO4}$ 90% w/w + isoamyl alcohol (isopentyl alcohol) and heating.

The acidic mixture separates into a black aqueous acidic phase (due to dehydration of the sugars, proteins, ...) and a colorless organic phase containing the partially esterified fat.

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=vORSXW_imUw&pp=ygUPZ2VyYmVyIGZhdCBtaWxr

A (sometimes pale, sometimes intense) violet-purple precipitate can be seen at the bottom of the butyrometer.

[image]

This is how it looks like in my experiment:

[image]

The violet-purple precipitate is also formed if milk is replaced with $\ce{H2O}$. This means that the purple substance is formed by mixing isoamyl alcohol + $\ce{H2SO4}$ alone.

The same purple color is seen in the synthesis of isoamyl acetate (banana oil), mixing isoamyl alcohol + glacial acetic acid + a drop of $\ce{H2SO4}$ 96% w/w and heating.

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=F9fGv9M_zyk&pp=ygUUYmFuYW5hIG9pbCBzeW50aGVzaXM%3D

[image]

I would like to know what this purple compound is.

I suppose it is a compound with a large conjugate system, perhaps due to the dehydration of isoamyl alcohol (formation of amylene) and subsequent partial polymerization.

Any ideas/references?

Ref.1 is the only source where the unusual color of the solution is explicitly indicated (the formation of the purple precipitate, which occurs on heating to more than $\pu{65 ^\circ C}$, is not indicated). Accordingly.

> II. To exaggerate the action and to see the effect of temperature, mixtures were made containing:

> a. Sulphuric acid: 10 c.c.; Amyl alcohol: 1 c.c.

> b. Sulphuric acid: 15 c.c.; Amy1 alcohol: 1.5 c.c.

> One series was cooled during mixture and kept at $\pu{14 ^\circ C}$  for fourteen hours, and the other series was not cooled and was left at $\pu{37 ^\circ C}$ for fourteen hours; water was then added to make up to 30 c.c., and the separated layer measured. The results were:

> 1. At temperature $\pu{14 ^\circ C}$: 0.295 c.c. H2SO4 + 0.590 c.c amyl alchol.

> 2. At temperature $\pu{37 ^\circ C}$: 0.424 c.c. H2SO4 + 0.800 c.c. amyl alchol.

> The layers at $\pu{14 ^\circ C}$ were nearly transparent, while at $\pu{37 ^\circ C}$ they were deeply coloured.

> III. Ten c.c. sulphuric acid, 11 c.c. of water, and 1 c.c. amyl alcohol (all at $\pu{29 ^\circ C}$) were mixed; no separation occurred in centrifugalizing, and the solution only became light brown. One c.c. amyl alcohol, 10 c.c. sulphuric acid, and 11 c.c. water (all at $\pu{29 ^\circ C}$) were mixed and centrifugalized, a liquid layer equivalent to about 0.2 per cent. fat was obtained, and the liquid became **violet**.

I hypothesize that perhaps at low temperature $\ce{H2SO4}$ can dehydrate isoamyl alcohol to amylene, but its polymerization is slow enough to allow the formation of low weight (with conjugated systems) soluble oligomers. At high temperatures the polymerization is faster and therefore large insoluble polymers are formed instead. In the synthesis of "banana oil", perhaps only the soluble compound is formed (not every times) since only a drop of $\ce{H2SO4}$ is used, so very little isoamyl alcohol is dehydrated to amylene.

The fact that it is not always visible could be due to the different amount of $\ce{H2SO4}$ used by different people (1 drop VS a few drops).

---

**Reference**:

1. H. Droop Richmond  and  F. R. O'shaughnessy, "Note on a possible source of error in modifications of the Leffmann-beam method for estimation of fat in milk," *Analyst* **1899**, *24*, 146-148 (DOI: DOI   https://doi.org/10.1039/AN8992400146).

Comment: Also note change to brown on neutralization. Good question.

Comment: It is very surprising that if we search Gerber's method and purple/violet precipitate, there are no relevant results.

Comment: Indeed. I thought the same thing. By heating to a basic pH, the same purple compound is not formed, even if the acidic pH is subsequently restored (unless if the solution is then heated).

Comment: In the cited publication (isoamyl alchol + H2SO4 at 29°C)  they say that the purple compound stratifies on the acidic aqueous phase. Therefore, I suppose that the purple compound is nonpolar.

Comment: Color of the gloves must be coincidental. :-P

Comment: There's a mistake in your quoting from the paper. The paper says in the "a" scenario, 0.295 cc sulfuric acid and 0.424 cc amyl alcohol are obtained. But your quote says 0.295 cc "a" and 0.424 cc "b" are obtained. While "a" and "b" are in fact depicting two scenarios, not two materials. There is the same mistake in 0.590 and 0.800 cc.